# Is there any missing operator in the vba code below?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I try to run the code below but i get a syntax error (missing operator) in line 3. I`m unable to figure out what is missing.

```
Dim mains As Recordset

Set mains = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MAIN CAMPUS MINOR POSITION APPLICANTS", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
mains.FindFirst "1st SECONDER='" & Nz(Me.txtmain, "") & "'"

If mains.NoMatch = True Then
Me.txtmain.BackColor = vbGreen
txtnakuru.SetFocus
Else
MsgBox "Duplicate First Seconder. Please Revise your Seconders.", vbExclamation, ""
Me.txtmain.Value = ""
```

What might i be ommiting.

Comment: Add brackets to fields that contain spaces, `[MAIN CAMPUS MINOR POSITION APPLICANTS]` and `[1st SECONDER]`.

Comment: Even better, don't use spaces nor punctuation/special characters nor all upper case in naming convention: `MainCampusMinorPositionApplicants`, `lstSeconder`.